# Looking for a paper by Vinberg

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, paper-request, diophantine-geometry

I have been reading about the Schinzel-Zassenhauss conjecture, and have been looking for the following reference:

Vinberg E.: On some number-theoretic conjectures of V. Arnold, Japanese J. Math., vol 2 (2007)

Unfortunately, despite extensive search, I haven't found the above paper I would really appreciate if someone could provide the paper or a link to the same. I would also like to ask if there is a website where I could find the articles of the Japanese Journal of Mathematics.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1007/s11537-007-0705-4

Comment: Interlibrary loan?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Do I need to get one to get access to the paper? How do I do so? Thanks. (Sorry I am not in a financial position to pay the amount mentioned in that link.)

Comment: @asrxiiviii Are you sure it is behind paywall? I have no subscription but can access it simply by clicking: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11537-007-0705-4.pdf

Comment: მამუკა ჯიბლაძე  Hi! Thank you for your answer. Through both the links above, I am getting redirected to the link (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11537-007-0705-4) which a Springer page containing the title, abstract and reference list of the paper, with two Access Options: 34,95 € and 63,02 € for article PDF and journal subscription respectively. Sorry, I am a little new to that site: should I sign in and/or go through some other formalities before getting access? Thank you.

Comment: If you are near a library, asr, you go up to a librarian and ask whether the library can get that paper for you. University libraries do this all the time for their faculty and students, other libraries may do it, too, and in my experience there's no charge for the service. Worth a try!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thank you so much. Unfortunately, I do not have any library nearby and my institute is shut down for the pandemic. Although most such online library-facilities are available for PhDs, postdocs and faculty of my institute (and I am an undergraduate student), I will try to contact those in charge of administration of my library to request for this. Fingers crossed!